# Exception Handling for Copy Activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, exception, azure-data-factory

I was using the copy activity for updating rows to azure table storage. Currently the pipeline fails if there are any errors in updating any of the rows/batches.

Is there a way to gracefully handle the failed rows and continue with the copy activity for the rest of the data?

I already tried the Fault Tolerance option which the copy activity provides but that does not solve this case.

[FaultTolerance Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvQnz.png)

Comment: Could you explain in detail why fault tolerance is not solving your case

Comment: I used the fault tolerance option and selected "skip incompatible rows". Still my pipeline fails when an incompatible row is encountered. 

Incompatible row is the record where I have intentionally added special characters to be copied as RowKey which is not supported by Azure Table Storage to check if the activity can handle this case.

Comment: The error I get - "FailedStorageOperation": "Element 25 in the batch returned an unexpected response code. 25:One of the request inputs is out of range.

Comment: What is the special character that is added in the row

Comment: These - "/, ?, \, #"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I have repro'd the same and got the same error when mapping the column containing special character data to RowKey column in Table Storage.

**Source dataset**
[image]

**Fault tolerance settings**
[image]

**Error Message:**

[image]

In copy activity, it is not possible to skip the incompatible rows other than using fault tolerance. Workaround is to use **dataflow activity** and separate the compatible rows and incompatible rows and then copy the compatible data using copy activity. Below is the approach.

- Source is taken as in below image.

[image]

- Since `col4` needs to be checked before loading to Table storage, Condition is given on col4 data using condition activity. **Conditional split Transformation** is added after source transformation. Condition is given as,
  **FalseStream** :
  `like(col4,'%#%')||like(col4,'%$%')||like(col4,'%/%')||like(col4,'%\\%')`

**Sample characters are given in the above condition. **

**True Stream** will be the rows which do not match the above condition.
[image]

- Both False and true Streams are added to Sink1 and sink2 respectively to copy the data to blob storage.
  **Output**:
  False Stream:
  [image]

True Stream Data:

[image]

- Once compatible data are copied to Blob, they can be copied to Table Storage using copy activity.